# Null Pointer Exception in output collector hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the output collector in the close method of the reduce class. The format for the output collector is `<Text, Text>`

I am passing the Text name_txt as the key, and Text val as the value.

I find that both Text name_txt and Text val are not null by printing them, but when I set the in the output, I get the null pointer exception at output.collect(name_str, val);

I have attached the code below for clarity. Pls help!

```
private OutputCollector<Text, Text> output;

public void close() throws IOException {          
  for(int i = 0; i<arraylist.size(); i++)
  {
    String name = arraylist.get(i).getToken();
    Text name_txt = new Text(name);
    System.out.println("name_txt: "+name_txt);
    Text val = new Text("hi");
    output.collect(name_txt, val);         
  }         
}
```

Comment: your output variable should be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you set the value of output?

I see you're using the old API (mapred), so you don't have the luxury of a setup method. Instead you'll probably have to add a conditional in your map method:

```
void map(K1 key, V1 value, OutputCollector<K2, V2> output, Reporter reporter)
  throws IOException {
  if (this.output == null) {
    this.output = output;
  }

  // your current map implementation goes here..
}
```